# Getting single results from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get results from a table, but if they repeat, I want to keep only the first one.
Example:

```
+-----+
| Row |
+-----+
| x1  |
| x1  |
| x2  |
| x3  |
| x4  |
| x4  |
| x5  |
+-----+
```

Output would be x1,x2,x3,x4,x5.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use group by on the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add to your sql query the **distinct** :

```
select distinct(row) from table
```

or on a php side with **array_unique**:

```
$unique_values = array_unique($rows);
```